# method of using scanf_s

Tags: c++, space

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    scanf_s("%d ", &i);

    printf("%d", i);
}
```

If I use space bar at `scanf_s,`, I have to use enter key twice to get a `printf("%d",i);` .

What is different between `scanf_s("%d",&i);` and `scanf_s("%d ",&i);`.

Answer (score 2):

scanf_s("%d ", &i); will require a blank character to be read after the number. this is why you have to press enter twice; enter counts as a blank character.